# Excel modify macro for "data from text" to open dialog box?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

So I work with CSV files and I need to open excel go to Data -> From text and format certain columns certain ways.
I recorded a macro that does that but it always opens the file I used when recording the macro. 
How do I modify the macro so it opens the dialog box and let me choose a file each time? 
I found this piece of code on the internet but I don't know how to integrate it with my recorded macro in VBA.

```
Dim MyFile As String
MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
```

Now how and where and what do I replace in the below macro (the code for which is created using the "record macro" button in excel)?

```
Sub random_name()
'
' random_name Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;MyFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "filename"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I have modified your code:

```
Sub random_name()
'
' random_name Macro
'

'
Dim connectioString As String

connectioString = "TEXT;" & ListFile


    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        connectioString _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "filename"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

beneth this paste this function:

```
Function ListFile()
' ----- Creating a dialog object -----------------------------------
    Dim oDiag As FileDialog
    Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Set oDiag = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    i = 0
    With oDiag
' ----- Going thru all of the files --------------------------------
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then

           ListFile = .SelectedItems(1)

        End If
    End With

    Set oDiag = Nothing

End Function
```

I am not at this point a 100% sure if filedialog required a reference tell me if it works :)

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm.
Could you just explain line 15 ".Name = "filename""
"filename" was put by me there to censor my actual used filename.

When I first recorded the macro it used to be ".Name = "<my file's actual name>"

So in reality this "filename" that is there right now relates to absolutely nothing yet it causes no problems - why is that? could it cause any problems in some situations?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi as far as I see in the documentation
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820914.aspx) 
The name can be anything you want it to be :) so you can replace that particular piece of code with anything. If you go in Excel Data -> Connections you will see it is under your filename.
You can however use this name to refer to it in VBA: ActiveSheet.QueryTables("filename").

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Path = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & Path, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
```